# Can we get an average in row wise for multiple columns in Dataflow ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Please refer the pic, I have to do that same thing but using dataflow

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Derived column activity` this activity helps you to create a new column trough data flow, give column name what you want and in expression give.

```sql
(col1+col2+col3)/3
```

[image]

***OUTPUT***

[image]